# Passing one instance of an object to different classes without using static or singleton

Tags: java, object, design-patterns

I am trying to figure out a way to pass one instance of the same class to multiple classes so I am able to build an object. The problem is it cannot be static or use singleton because many users will be hitting the application at the same time and I may run into other issues. Are there any design patterns that would work best with this scenario or if there is some way to use global variables in java? I am trying implement this with an existing rest service that was not designed very well.

```
    public class OneInstanceOf
    {//I want to build this map object without static
    private Map<String, String> mapIwantToBuild = new HaspMap<String, String>();
    public void methodIwantToCall(String name, String value)
    {mapIwantToBuild.put(name, value)  
    }
```

Comment: Please make your question much more concrete and specific by showing your [mcve] code and by explaining the problem in more concrete and real-code terms.

Comment: Pass instance A (of class A) to instance B (of class B) in its' constructor. And yes, you can use a DI framework like Guice or Spring to control these intra-class dependencies.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are looking to create a M-V-C (Model-View-Controller) structure or one of its many variants, but without more information, there's no way that I'd post this guess as an answer.

Comment: If your code is well-coded and thread-safe, using a singleton should not be a problem, even if multiple hits happen at the same time. Why would this be a problem? Servlet and Spring uses massively singleton and there is no problem with that.

Comment: "One instance to be passed to multiple classes", isn't that practically a singleton? How are you planning to make it thread-safe?

Comment: It needn't be a singleton if you merely create an instance and pass it to method or constructor calls. You pass to methods and constructors, not classes _per se_. Just pass the reference. Is there some complication that would make that not work? To learn how to pass method and constructor arguments, read the Java Tutorial.

Comment: @Ernest whether or not a class purports to be singleton, you would need to consider the thread safety if a single instance can be used by multiple threads. Singleton-ness just isn't relevant to that question.

Comment: @AndyTurner Exactly, what I didn't get was a need to have a single instance (read that in references to static variables, etc.) used across threads (read that in many users at the same time). This seemed to me like, "a singleton of some sort, exposed to concurrent access, but immune to thread-safety challenges", and there's no easy answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

The common pattern for you task is dependency injection. You can use spring framework for that task.

1.Create configuration with your bean:

```
@Configuration    
public class YourConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public OneInstanceOf oneInstanceOf {
        return new OneInstanceOf();
    }
}
```

2.Inject your bean whatever you want (simplest - use autowiring):

```
@Component
public class Client1 {
    @Autowire
    private OneInstanceOf oneInstanceOf;

    public void someMethod() {
        oneInstanceOf.methodIwantToCall();
    }
}
```

Spring will insure single instance of oneInstanceOf will be injected in all clients.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but trying to reference that bean in Client1 and it is null... (spring boot app)

Comment: Did you add your configuration class to Main application class? 
@Import({YourConfiguration.class1})

Answer (score -2):

U can create a setter with parameter of instance class variable, in every class in which you want to pass the instance. Then create a method in one of the classes that calls setter of all those classes and pass parameter instance as parameter to that method.
Like below.

```
class A{
    B b = new B;
    set(B b){
        C.setB(b);
        D.setB(b);
        E.setB(b);
    }
}
```